# Built in function all() and any() in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the built-in functions of all(). The code below should print 'fail' but instead gives me a 'success'. Could anyone tell me why this happens?

```
test = np.array([9.,-1.,2.,3.,5.])

if test[:].all() > 0.:
    print 'success'
else:
    print 'fail'
```

Comment: Here `.all()` is not a built-in function.

Comment: And why should it fail anyway? All the values in the `test` array are non-zero (and hence `True` in boolean context) , and this results in `True` (which can be considered as 1 in integer context), which is greater than `0.`

Comment: What exactly were you trying to achieve with `.all()` ?

Comment: As it is you are just asking if [9.,-1.,2.,3.,5.] is greater than 0, not if contained items are!

Comment: I was hoping that the if sentence would judge whether all the elements were positive or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others mentioned in comments, `all()` is a boolean function, so it's just looking if all elements are not 0 (aka `False`).

This is how you want to be using `all()` for your specific case.  It uses a generator comprehension to make an iterable of `True` and `False` based on the original array.  It will return `False` if any element is less than or equal to zero.

```
all(i > 0 for i in test)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted!!